# Testing Android ContentProvider that accesses the Internet

Tags: android, unit-testing, http, junit, android-2.2-froyo

I've written my own Android `ContentProvider` for accessing certain Internet resources.  I'm trying to write some unit tests, but I do not want those tests to actually access the Internet.

Behind the scenes, my code is using the `DefaultHttpClient` class to access the web.  Basically, I'd like to know how I can use the `ProviderTestCase2` class to intercept any HTTP requests and return a predefined String "response" instead.

I'm assuming there is something I can mock inside either `ContentResolver` or `Context` to do this, but I need a bit of guidance.

Comment: Can't you rather locally host your "mock" server which handles your request and response ?